How to exclude calls that are being done inside a logger when using PIT Mutation Testing?
I'm using PIT mutation testing in a Java project (version 21), and I'm facing an issue regarding the exclusion of log calls from the mutation process.
In my codebase, I have several log statements that I don't want to cover with unit tests, some of which contain method calls to retrieve data. For example, I have log statements like this example:
log.info("Id={}, name={}", foo.getId(), foo.getName())

All my classes and lines are covered (with mutants killed) in the project except for these log files, that are reporting surviving mutants:
1. removed call to com/project/Foo::getId → SURVIVED
2. removed call to com/project/Foo::getName → SURVIVED

I want to configure PIT to exclude any method calls within the logger from the mutation process. However, I still want PIT to evaluate the rest of the codebase for mutations.
Is there a way to achieve this with PIT? I've looked into using exclusion configurations in the official documentation, stackoverflow and PIT dev chats, but I couldn't find a way to specifically exclude method calls within log statements.
Any help or guidance on how to configure PIT to exclude the log method calls from mutation testing would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried with configurations in the pom like avoidCallsTo (avoinding call to logger interfaces) and with the feature +FLOGCALL, but this is only preventing mutants to be created for basic logs, it is still evaluating the methods that are inside these log methods.
